# Limitar valor do input com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como limitar o valor no meu input? 
Tentei usar não funcionou usar **min="1"** e  **max="3"**

```js
function process(quant){
               var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("quant").value);
               value+=quant;
               if(value < 1){
                 document.getElementById("quant").value = 1;
               }else{
               document.getElementById("quant").value = value;
               }
             }
```

```html
  <div data-app="product.quantity" id="quantidade">
            <span id="span_erro_carrinho" class="blocoAlerta" style="display:none;">Selecione uma opção                   para variação do produto</span>
            <label>Quantidade:</label>
            <input type="button" id="plus" value='-' onclick="process(-1)" />
            <input id="quant" name="quant" class="text" min="1" max="3" size="1" type="text" value="1"  maxlength="5" oninput="checa(this)" />

            <input type="button" id="minus" value='+' min="1" max="3" onclick="process(1)">
          </div>
```

Comment: Pra usar o min e max seu campo tem que ser do tipo `type="number"`

Comment: Sim, isso funcionar se eu digitar no campo, porem se eu usar as setas para aumentar e diminuir o valor ele não limite nem mesmo se usar type="number"

Comment: Ainda não resolve. veja como esta meu codigo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/451755/limitar-valor-do-input-com-javascript?noredirect=1#comment864086_451755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que falta na verdade é simplificar o código para então visualizar o problema.

Primeiro endentei o código e depois tirei o elefante `...document.getElementById("quant")...` de dentro da s̶a̶l̶a̶ função. Então pude visualizar o problema que consistia em apenas limitar o contradomínio.

```js
let input = document.getElementById("quant");

function process(quant) {
  var value = parseInt(input.value);
  value += quant;
  if (value < input.min) return;
  if (value > input.max) return;
  input.value = value;
}
```

```html
<label>Quantidade:</label>
<input type="button" id="plus" value='-' onclick="process(-1)" />
<input type="text" id="quant" name="quant" class="text" min="1" max="3" size="1" value="1" maxlength="5" readonly/>
<input type="button" id="minus" value='+' min="1" max="3" onclick="process(1)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reescreva seu código JavaScript assim:**

```
function process(quant) {
            var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("quant").value);
            value+=quant;
            if(value <= 1){
                value = 1;
                document.getElementById("quant").value = 1;
            }
            else if (value >= 3) {
                value = 3;
                document.getElementById("quant").value = 3;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("quant").value = value;
            }
        }
```

Outra forma interessante de reutilizar a função e poupar tempo, é usar **outros dois parâmetros** para definir o valor **máximo** e **mínimo** (onde são passados pelo HTML), e poder utilizar a mesma função conforme a necessidade:

**Altere o código JavaScript para:**

```
function process(quant, max, min) {
            var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("quant").value);
            value+=quant;
            if(value <= min){
                value = min;
                document.getElementById("quant").value = min;
            }
            else if (value >= max) {
                value = max;
                document.getElementById("quant").value = max;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("quant").value = value;
            }
        }
```

**Altere os botões no HTML para:**

```
<input type="button" id="plus" value='-' onclick="process(-1, 10, 1)" />
<input type="button" id="minus" value='+' onclick="process(1, 10, 1)">
```

Desta forma é possível passar um valor personalizado para determinado produto, lembrando que **o segundo parâmetro é o valor máximo** e **o terceiro é o valor mínimo**.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar o `maxlength` do HTML, um exemplo básico

```html
<input id="quant" name="quant" class="text" size="1" type="text" value="1"  maxlength="5" oninput="checa(this)" />
```

Sem os `min` e `max`. Eu uso tranquilamente o `maxlength` e sempre da certo.
Bom, mas para o seu caso que envolve botão junto, daria pra fazer uma forma que os botões tivessem um click máximo, usando a propriedade `disabled`.
Talvez este post no StackoverFlow ajude [Limit click button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841632/limit-click-button-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Altere o tipo do atributo do html para `number`:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="10">
```